# Recursion puzzle with key in the box

Tags: python, recursion

I currently try to understand recursion on made up example. Imagine you have a briefcase, which can be opened by the key. The key is in the big box, which can contain other smaller boxes, which key might be in.

In my example boxes are lists. The recursion appears when we find the smaller box - we search it for the key. The problem is that my function can find the key if it is actually in the box and can't go back if there is nothing like 'key'.

Unfortunately, i could not understand how to go back if there is no key in the smaller box. Can you help me solve this puzzle? By the way, have a nice day! Here is the code (big box consists in the way when the key can be found and returned):

```
box = ['socks', 'papers', ['jewelry', 'flashlight', 'key'], 'dishes', 'souvernirs', 'posters']

def look_for_key(box):
    for item in box:
        if isinstance(item, list) == True:
            look_for_key(item)
        elif item == 'key':
            print('found the key')
    key = item
    return key

print(look_for_key(box))
```

Comment: make sure you return the value from the recursive call:  ```return look_for_key(item)```

Comment: It does not really matter:
https://prnt.sc/22mv16s

Comment: @AbbeGijly You don't want to just return the recursive call's value without checking i f it is `None` first. Otherwise, you could miss out on finding the item elsewhere.

Comment: You may as well just return `True` or `False`, as the function is hardcoded to look for the value `'key'`; the caller knows what item, if any, will be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iteration

The most closed to yours and yet readable solution I could find is:

```
def look_for_key(box):
    for item in box:
        if item == 'key':
            return item
        elif isinstance(item, list) and look_for_key(item) is not None:
            return look_for_key(item)
        else:
            pass

box = [['sock','papers'],['jewelry','key']]
look_for_key(box)
# ==> 'key'
```

I don't like it because its deduction condition includes a recursive call which is hard to interpret. It does not help to improve interpretability if you assign `look_for_key(item)` to a variable and check for `not None` afterwards. It is just similarly difficult to interpret. An equivalent but more interpretable solution is:

```
def look_for_key(box):
    def inner(item, remained):
        if item == [] and remained == []:
            return None
        elif isinstance(item, list) and item != []:
            return inner(item[0], [item[1:], remained])
        elif item == [] or item != 'key':
            return inner(remained[0], remained[1:])
        elif item == 'key':
            return item
    return inner(box[0], box[1:])

box = [['sock','papers'],['jewelry','key']]
look_for_key(box)
# ==> 'key'
```

It explicitly splits the tree to branches (see below what this means) with `return inner(item[0], [item[1:], remained])` and `return inner(remained[0], remained[1:])` instead of intrinsically reusing the recursive call conditionally during deduction - `if look_for_key(item) is not None: return look_for_key(item)` - with this line of code it is hard to see a diagram and understand in which direction the recursion goes.

The 2nd solution also makes it easier to infer the complexity using a tree diagram since you see the branches explicitly, for example `remained[0]` vs. `remained[1:]`.

As `inner` is simply an iteration written in a functional way and `for` loop is a syntactic sugar to form iteration, both solutions should have similar complexity in principle.

Since you do not just want a solution but also a better understanding of recursion, I would try the following approach.

### Mapping over Trees (Map-Reduce)

This is a typical text book tree recursion question. What you want is to traverse a hieratical data structure called tree. A typical solution is mapping a function over the tree:

```
from functools import reduce
def look_for_key(tree):
    def look_inner(sub_tree):
        if isinstance(sub_tree, list):
            return look_for_key(sub_tree)
        elif sub_tree == 'key':
            return [sub_tree]
        else:
            return []
    return reduce(lambda left_branch, right_branch: look_inner(left_branch) + look_inner(right_branch), tree, [])

box = ['socks', 'papers', ['jewelry', 'flashlight', 'key'], 'dishes', 'souvernirs', 'posters']
look_for_key(box)
# ==> ['key']
```

To make it explicit I use `tree`, `sub_tree`, `left_branch`, `right_branch` as variable names instead of `box`, `inner_box` and so on as in your example. Notice how the function `look_for_key` is mapped over each `left_branch` and `right_branch` of the `sub_tree`s in the `tree`. The result is then summarized using `reduce` (A classic [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) procedure).

To be more clear, you can omit the `reduce` part and keep only the `map` part:

```
def look_for_key(tree):
    def look_inner(sub_tree):
        if isinstance(sub_tree, list):
            return look_for_key(sub_tree)
        elif sub_tree == 'key':
            return sub_tree
        else:
            return None 
    return list(map(look_inner, tree))

look_for_key(box)
# ==> [None, None, [None, None, 'key'], None, None, None]
```

This does not generate your intended format of the result. But it helps to understand how the recursion works. `map` just adds an abstract layer to recursively look for keys into sub trees which is equivalent to the syntactic sugar of `for` loop provided by python. That is not important. The essential thing is decomposing the tree properly (deduction) and set-up proper base condition to return the result.

### Native Tree Recursion

If it is still not clear enough, you can get rid of all abstractions and syntactic sugars and just build a native recursion from scratch:

```
def look_for_key(box):
    if box == []:
        return [] 
    elif not isinstance(box, list) and box == 'key':
        print('found the key')
        return [box]
    elif not isinstance(box, list) and box != 'key':
        return []
    else:
        return look_for_key(box[0]) + look_for_key(box[1:])

look_for_key(box)
# ==> found the key
# ==> ['key']
```

Here all three fundamental elements of recursion:

- base cases
- deduction
- recursive calls

are explicitly displayed. You can also see from this example clearly that there is no miracle of going out of an inner box (or sub-tree). To look into every possible corner inside the box (or tree), you just repeatedly split it to two parts in every smaller box (or sub tree). Then you properly combine your results at each level ([so called fold or reduce or accumulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))), here using `+`, then recursive calls will take care of it and help to return to the top level.

Both the native recursion and map-reduce approaches are able to find out multiple keys, because they traverse over the whole tree and accumulate all matches:

```
box = ['a','key','c', ['e', ['f','key']]]
look_for_key(box)
# ==> found the key
# ==> found the key
# ==> ['key', 'key']
```

### Recursion Visualization

Finally, to fully understand what is going on with the tree recursion, you could plot the recursive depth and visualize how the calls are moving to deeper levels and then returned.

```
import functools 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ignore the error of unhashable data type
def ignore_unhashable(func): 
    uncached = func.__wrapped__
    attributes = functools.WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS + ('cache_info', 'cache_clear')
    @functools.wraps(func, assigned=attributes) 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
        try: 
            return func(*args, **kwargs) 
        except TypeError as error: 
            if 'unhashable type' in str(error): 
                return uncached(*args, **kwargs) 
            raise 
    wrapper.__uncached__ = uncached
    return wrapper

# rewrite the native recursion and cache the recursive calls
@ignore_unhashable
@functools.lru_cache(None)
def look_for_key(box):
    global depth, depths
    depth += 1
    depths.append(depth)
    result = ([] if box == [] else
              [box] if not isinstance(box, list) and box == 'key' else
              [] if not isinstance(box, list) and box != 'key' else
              look_for_key(box[0]) + look_for_key(box[1:]))
    depth -= 1
    return result
    
# function to plot recursion depth
def plot_depths(f, *args, show=slice(None), **kwargs):
    """Plot the call depths for a cached recursive function"""
    global depth, depths
    depth, depths = 0, []
    f.cache_clear()
    f(*args, **kwargs)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.xlabel('Recursive Call Number'); plt.ylabel('Recursion Depth')
    X, Y = range(1, len(depths) + 1), depths
    plt.plot(X[show], Y[show], '.-')
    plt.grid(True); plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

box = ['socks', 'papers', ['jewelry', 'flashlight', 'key'], 'dishes', 'souvernirs']
plot_depths(look_for_key, box)
```

[image: Visualization of Recursion Depth]
Whenever the function got called recursively, the curve goes to a deeper level - the **downward slash**. When the tree/sub-tree is splitted to left and right branches, two calls happen at the same level - the **horizontal line** that connected **two dots** (two calls `look_for_key(box[0]) + look_for_key(box[1:])`). When it traverses
over a complete sub-tree (or branch) and reaches to the last leave in that sub-tree (a base condition when a value or `[]` is returned), it starts to go back to upper levels - the **valley** in the curve. If you have multiple sub/nest lists there will be multiple valleys. Eventually it traverses over the whole tree and returns the results

You can play with boxes (or trees) of different nest structures to understand better how it works. Hopefully these provide you enough information and a more comprehensive understanding of tree-recursion.

Comment: thank you so much for your absolutely amazing answer. Honestly, i did not expect anything like it in my post. The understanding of all above would take a while for me because of my skills and the fact that I am not native English-speaker, but I'll try my best. Thanks again and have a great Christmas holidays, if you have ones, of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

Integrating the above comments:

```
box = ['socks', 'papers', ['jewelry', 'flashlight', 'key'], 'dishes', 'souvernirs', 'posters']

def look_for_key(box):
    for item in box:
        if isinstance(item, list) == True:
            in_box = look_for_key(item)
            if in_box is not None:
                return in_box
        elif item == 'key':
            print('found the key')
            return item
    # not found
    return None

print(look_for_key(box))
```

which prints:

```
found the key
key
```

If the key is deleted from the box, executing the code prints:

```
None
```

Comment: This is not a bad solution. However, it is bit hard to read and interpret since assignment is used within one of the base condition and result of recursive call is conditionally returned. This complexity breaks the simplicity and beauty of a recursive solution. Maybe you could simplify it? Also this solution does not handle the case of multiple keys `box = ['a','key','c', ['e', ['f','key']]]`. See the other solution for example.

Comment: thanks -- i was going for a solution that made minimum edits to your original to get it running